# Wobble physics like Sandwich Runner Unity3d

Tags: physics, rope-physics

Here's the game, that's the wobble! [image: That's it again]I am trying to make a hypercasual game similar to Sandwich Runner, I can't quite figure out how the wobble mechanics was made! Where the stacked objects wobble when you move them

Comment: Keep in mind that most folks here don't know the game you're talking about and have never played it. You should add references here so that we know exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks! I just uploaded some images to show what i mean, i tried using hinge joints but it's wobbly as hell! And it's just not smooth enough like the one here, is there a different way to approach this problem?

Comment: [I've done some bobblehead physics with Verlet integration in the past](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/900198691390328832). [Here's the script for that](https://pastebin.com/BLC6YEtz) (though looking at it now, years later, I can see the interpolation code is wrong). That might offer a starting point.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! Are all the objects connected supposed to hold this script?